# Collecting custom URL parameters into Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm using several UTM parameters to pass data to Analytics; it works great and is easy to find in reports.  Can I record custom URL parameters somehow into Analytics?  I tried creating a custom dimension, but passing a custom URL parameter with the event parameter set in that custom dimension didn't work.